# A library is installed with `yum install` but not with `yum update`

Tags: cmake, rpm, yum, intel-mkl

In my CMakeLists.txt, I have the following:

```
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_REQUIRES "boost148, intel-daal-core-2018.1-163, \
  intel-mkl-core-2018.1-163")
```

My problem is that when I do a `yum install,`the *intel-mkl-core-2018.1-163* library gets installed, but when I do `yum update` on a machine that did not have *intel-mkl-core* - it does not get installed.

I also tried `yum upgrade`, with the same results.

**The above does not seem to be the correct behaviour. Any suggestions on how to debug this issue?**

(OS: CentOS/RedHat 7)

Answer (score 0):

`yum update` means: update every currently installed package. If `intel-mkl-core` was not installed before, it won't be *updated*...

`yum install` means: install (or update) this package even if it was not installed before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Chris. 
However, the library that does not get installed is a _dependency_ (`CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_REQUIRES`) of an RPM which DOES get updated.

Comment: That should indeed not happen. In that case, you can query your installed packages to see how that could happen: `rpm -q <packagename> --requires` or `--provides`. `rpm -V <packagename>` to verify the installed package (its files and dependencies)